# React Router Link brakes the website if clicked while is animated

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gsap, locomotive-scroll

I've implemented a horizontal scroll animation using `gsap` for a projects section, but I've run into an issue. When I click on a project that is currently being animated by `gsap`, my entire portfolio breaks. The `Link` tag from `React Router` does change the URL, but the component from the `Route element` is not rendered, leaving me with a blank page.

[image]

I do use `locomotiveScroll` and I also created a `custom hook` to make `locomotiveScroll` work with `gsap's ScrollTrigger`.
Could this be because `locomotiveScroll` gets confused when `React Router` changes routes and keeps the "page" in the same position, a position that might not exist on the second page?
Did anyone else have the same problem? I would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you.

**P.S.** I do not get any errors in the console.

Here is some code that may help

```
            <Link
              to={`/projects/${project.id}`}
              className={styles.link}
              id='link'
            >
              <div
                id='projectImageContainer'
                className={styles.projectImageContainer}
                onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
              >
                {/* <AnimatedImage src={project.image} playAnim={hover} /> */}
              </div>
            </Link>
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    const scrollContext = gsap.context(() => {
      scrollTl.current = gsap.timeline({
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: projectsContainerRef.current,
          scroller: '.App',
          start: 'top top',
          end: `+=${trackRef.current.offsetWidth}`,
          pin: true,
          scrub: 0.5,
        },
      });

      scrollTl.current
        .to(trackRef.current, {
          xPercent: -100,
          ease: 'none',
        })
        .to(
          titleRef.current,
          {
            xPercent: -50,
            ease: 'none',
          },
          '<'
        );
    });

    return () => scrollContext.revert();
  }, []);
```